# Keras: layer trainable set false not working

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have a pretrained keras based Bidirectional LSTM based model. I want to set trainable false for the first few layers. But it is not working.

```
 classifier.layers[1].trainable=False
```

I also tried creating a dummy copy of the model using config with trainable key changed to false. But even the weights of that dummy model change after training.

Comment: Try `classifier.compile` after `trainable=False`.

Comment: @DanielMöller I tried. Not working

Comment: Is it a multi-level model? Does `classifier.layers[1].layers` exist?

Comment: No. It says layer has no attribute layers. It is bidirectional wrapper LSTM layer.

Comment: This should not be happening, but you can try these three together: `layers[i].forward_layer.trainable = False`, `layers[i].backward_layer.trainable = False` and `layers[i].trainable = False`. And use `compile` after that.

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since something is strange, you can try to deeply find all the layers involved and set `trainable=False` in all of them:

```
classifier.layers[i].forward_layer.trainable = False
classifier.layers[i].backward_layer.trainable = False 
classifier.layers[i].trainable = False
```

And use `classifier.compile` after that.

In case your model involves submodels, you might need recurrency:

```
classifier.layers[i].layers[j].trainable = False
```